Is there a type that corresponds to "nothing" in the JSX (different from undefined or null)
In React with TypeScript, I'm looking for a way to type children on a component so that it can accept 1 or 2 ReactElement, and I was wondering if there is a way to type something as, for example, ReactElement | nothing, for the 2nd element, where "nothing" is the equivalent of it not being declared in the JSX at all (so, different from undefined or null).
I know you can use ReactElement | [ReactElement, ReactElement] to say "either 1 or 2 ReactElement", but that gets annoying the more elements you add.
In the code below, ExampleUseOne is fine but ExampleUseTwo isn't, which makes sense.
I'm wondering if there's a type I can add to the 2nd children that would make both examples work.
import React, { ReactElement } from "react";

type Props = {
  children: [ReactElement, ReactElement | null];
}

const Component = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>{children}</div>
  );
};

const Part = () => {
  return <div>Part</div>;
};

const ExampleUseOne = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {
  return (
    <Component>
      <Part />
      {/*  returns `ReactElement` or `null` so TS is ok with it */}
      {hasTwoParts ? <Part /> : null}
    </Component>
  )
}

const ExampleUseTwo = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {
  return (
    <Component>
      <Part />
      {/* nothing declared here, so TS is complaining that it doesn't match the type signature */}
    </Component>
  )
}

Here's the TS Playground link for the above.
Finally, I know that ReactElement | [ReactElement, ReactElement | null] works in this case, but it seems silly to have to repeat the 1st element since it doesn't change. So, for the 2nd element, is there a type, call it T, I can add that matches the element not being defined in the JSX, so that I can use for the whole children type this: [ReactElement, ReactElement | null | T]?
I tried using the several special types I know: never, unknown, void, undefined, to no avail.

You can use ReactNode, it accepts everything React can render: Boolean, String, Number, null, undefined, React element or an array of all these types
type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
}

...

// OK
const ExampleUseOne = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {

  return (
    <Component>
      <Part />
      {hasTwoParts ? <Part /> : null}
    </Component>
  )
}

// OK
const ExampleUseTwo = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {
  return (
    <Component>
      <Part />
    </Component>
  )
}

TS Playground
You could also use a union ReactElement | [ReactElement, ReactElement] and use a Fragment <></> in the case of hasTwoParts === false:
type Props = {
  children: ReactElement | [ReactElement, ReactElement];
}

...

// OK
const ExampleUseOne = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {

  return (
    <Component>
      <Part />
      {hasTwoParts ? <Part /> : <></>}
    </Component>
  )
}

// OK
const ExampleUseTwo = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {
  return (
    <Component>
      <Part />
    </Component>
  )
}

TS Playground
Another option is to type children as ReactElement and put your elements in a Fragment as follows:
type Props = {
  children: ReactElement;
}

...

// OK
const ExampleUseOne = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {

  return (
    <Component>
      <>
        <Part />
        {hasTwoParts ? <Part /> : null}
      </>
    </Component>
  )
}

// OK
const ExampleUseTwo = ({ hasTwoParts }: { hasTwoParts?: boolean }) => {
  return (
    <Component>
      <Part />
    </Component>
  )
}


There are many ways to make this work, yes, but I was just wondering if there was a special type I didn't know about that I could use. The thing is, I don't think the consumer of the component should have to know how it's implemented, they should just be able to use one <Part /> or two depending on their need without having to hack it in. I know it's not perfect because they can still hack it in, and the type safety provided by TS for this case is very thin at best, but still :D

@bvaugenot With [ReactElement, ReactElement | null | T] you're obligated to provide the second value. Does ReactNode meet your needs ? I updated my answer with an example


With [ReactElement, ReactElement | null | T] you're obligated to provide the second value
Yes, that's true. In my real case, I need 2 or 3 ReactElement, so this is not an issue.
As for using ReactNode, the idea is to restrict what can be passed, up to a reasonable level anyway, so obviously ReactNode is kind of the opposite of that
Again, it's not a "problem" that I have, I was just curious to know if there were any shorter alternative to listing all the possible variations of the type just because the one ReactElement in it happens to be optional.


You need 2 or 3 optional ReactEelement, you can achieve that with [ReactElement, ReactElement?] but you must provide a single element in array form as well <Component>{[<Part />]}</Component> TS Playground

Oh, I didn't even think you could use ? inside of that! That actually works much better for me in my real world case (the one with 2 or 3 ReactElement), so thanks!
I have to say, now that I know this, I would have expected [ReactEl, ReactEl] | [ReactEl, ReactEl, ReactEl] to be equivalent to [ReactEl, ReactEl, ReactEl?], but it doesn't seem to be the case (TS playground).

I added comments to your TS playground

Thanks for the help! So I guess the answer to my original question is that there is no such type that can be used, but one can create it, like: type NonRenderable = boolean | null | undefined; and then use that: [ReactEl, ReactEl, ReactEl | NonRenderable], to account for all the ways something might be "not provided" in the JSX, be it via not putting it at all, conditionally put it via ternary operator, or && operator.
